# Appending Comprehensive Function Iterations python 3.6

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

#### I am trying to complete the selectionSort, and have it return a new list made up of the initial list plus the comprehensive iterations of that list as it's solved.

```
def selectionSort(A):
    log = []
    #log.append(A)
    for i in range(0, len(A) - 1): 
        minIndex = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
            if A[j] < A[minIndex]:
                minIndex = j
        if minIndex != i:
            A[i], A[minIndex] = A[minIndex], A[i]
    return log


num_list = [10, 9, 8, 7]
```

print(selectionSort(num_list))

> [7, 8, 9, 10]

#### I'm looking for something like:

> [10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 10, 7, 8, 9, 10]

#### notice how it is three iterations of the initial list.

I got this to work with BubbleSort and even MergeSort, but they were very different - this method of trading indices doesn't seem to allow you to bucket the function as it changes. It appears that the list is changed in memory; log.append(A) returns the solved list :(
Thanks for any help.

Oh yeah I'm using python 3.6 in Anaconda

Comment: this sort is mutating the array it's working on. I think your first step would be to modify the sort to work on a new array instead of mutating it's parameter

Comment: To get a "current state" for your log, you need to copy the current list. Your first line inside the outer loop should be `log.append(A[:])`.

Comment: as a side note, please don't use `range(len(A))` if you need the index, use `for i, elem in enumerate(A)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like this. Thx for the suggestions!

```
def selectionSort(A):
    for i, elem in enumerate(A):
        minIndex = i
        log.append(A[:])
        for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
            if A[j] < A[minIndex]: 
                minIndex = j
        if minIndex != i:
            A[i], A[minIndex] = A[minIndex], A[i]
    while log[-1] == log[-2]:
        log.remove(log[-1])
    return log

num_list = [10, 9, 8, 7]
log = []
print(selectionSort(num_list))
```

> [[10, 9, 8, 7], [7, 9, 8, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `log` in the beginning. You can also do `log = [i for elem in log for i in elem]` before returning `log` to have the result of your function look exactly like OP's desired result.